# C# read Arduino

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to make a app that read the outgoing signals from Arduino, but I can't make it work in C# [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), only in the console. Is my C# Windows Forms code wrong? I don't get any errors when I debug, but it doesn't mean that I haven't forgot something.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace CommunicateWithArduino
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static System.IO.Ports.SerialPort port;

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        private BackgroundWorker hardWorker;

        private Thread readThread = null;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            hardWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            sendBtn.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.ComponentModel.IContainer components =
                new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
            port.PortName = comPort.SelectedItem.ToString();
            port.BaudRate = Int32.Parse(baudRate.SelectedItem.ToString());
            port.DtrEnable = true;
            port.ReadTimeout = 5000;
            port.WriteTimeout = 500;
            port.Open();

            readThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Read));
            readThread.Start();
            this.hardWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

            btnConnect.Text = "<Connected>";

            btnConnect.Enabled = false;
            comPort.Enabled = false;
            sendBtn.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                comPort.Items.Add(s);
            }
            if (comPort.Items.Count > 0)
                comPort.SelectedIndex = comPort.Items.Count-1;
            else
                comPort.SelectedIndex = 0;

            baudRate.Items.Add("2400");
            baudRate.Items.Add("4800");
            baudRate.Items.Add("9600");
            baudRate.Items.Add("14400");
            baudRate.Items.Add("19200");
            baudRate.Items.Add("28800");
            baudRate.Items.Add("38400");
            baudRate.Items.Add("57600");
            baudRate.Items.Add("115200");

            baudRate.SelectedIndex = 2;
        }

        private void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Write(sendText.Text);
            }
        }

        private void SetText(string text)
        {

            if (this.receiveText.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.receiveText.Text += "Text: ";
                this.receiveText.Text += text;
                this.receiveText.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        public void Read()
        {
            while (port.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (port.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        string message = port.ReadLine();
                        this.SetText(message);
                    }
                }
                catch (TimeoutException) { }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(!(readThread == null))
                    readThread.Abort();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
            }

            try
            {
                port.Close();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Do you receive data on the serialport, or can't you get the data from thread to gui?

Comment: If you don't know, you could: 1, log the serial data to a file, and 2, create a thread that calls `SetText`every 5th second or so.

Comment: I cant get data on the serial port in c# winform app. but in the arduino programs serial monitor i get data and i can get data on my c# console app to so there are no wrong with the arduino. but i can not get data in my winform this is driving me crazy cus i dont think there are any wrong with my winform code i posted. I writen the app so i can send data and recive data in a text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the ReadLine method will block until a line is received. Is your Arduino program sending a line? Did you close the Arduino serial monitor program while running your program?

I would change to port.ReadChar until you verify that you are receiving characters.

Comment: Yes arduino its sending a line. I am using the example sketch "Serial Call and Response" that comes with the arduino programmer app. I cant run the Arduino serial monitor program while i run my program. i need to close one to run the other. I cant understand whats wrong becuse its working in c# consloe and arduino serial monitor and not in C# winform the code i posted.

Comment: can you debug.print any characters you receive to verify the program is configuring the port correctly?

Comment: The Serial Call and Response example that I just looked at is not sending a line. It is sending a single character "A" ( Serial.print('A'); ) and waiting for a response from you.

Comment: Jeff your right !! i changed Serial.print('A'); to Serial.println('A'); and it started to work tnx man.