# how to read and send data via serial port in the same program in asp C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I am already send data from C# to `Arduino`, and it's work perfect; but when I try to receive data on C# from sensors by `event handler`, it must keep port open to read any received data; so I can't send data via serial port any more.

How can I send and receive data **at the same time** between C# and Arduino?

This is my code to receive data:

```
public static SerialPort port=
    new SerialPort("COM5", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

protected void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    SerialPort sp=(SerialPort)sender;
    indata=sp.ReadExisting();
    Functions f=new Functions();

    if(indata!="") {
        if(indata.Equals("bed_light_on\r\n")) {
            f.update_flag("bed_light", 1);
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    indata="";
    port.Close();
    port.DataReceived+=new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceived);

    if(!port.IsOpen)
        port.Open();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this from an ASP.NET application?

Comment: check that asking code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663116/c-sharp-read-arduino

Comment: You either need to use separate threads for reading and writing or use asynchronous operations.  If this really is ASP then you have the added issue that the application may start and stop unpredictably.

Comment: A sanity check is indicated here.  ASP code runs on a webserver.  Typically in data center or server room.  Behind a locked door, no Arduinos allowed inside.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helper class I wrote 6 years that may help. BTW - you can't read COM ports from ASP :)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class COMSerialPort : IDisposable
    {
        private SerialPort FSerialPort;
        public Boolean Disposed { get; private set; }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public COMSerialPort(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Encoding encode)
        {
            FSerialPort = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            FSerialPort.NewLine = "\r";
            FSerialPort.Encoding = encode;
            Disposed = false;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public COMSerialPort(String portName, Int32 baudRate) : this( portName, baudRate, Encoding.ASCII )
        {
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        ~COMSerialPort()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        protected void Dispose(Boolean bDisposing)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (!Disposed)
                {
                    Disposed = true;
                    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

                    if (bDisposing)
                    {
                        if (FSerialPort != null)
                        {
                            Close();

                            FSerialPort.Dispose();
                            FSerialPort = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void Open()
        {
            if (!FSerialPort.IsOpen) FSerialPort.Open();
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void Close()
        {
            if (FSerialPort.IsOpen) FSerialPort.Close();
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void WriteLine(String data)
        {
            if (FSerialPort.IsOpen) FSerialPort.WriteLine(data);
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void Write(String data)
        {
            if (FSerialPort.IsOpen) FSerialPort.Write(data);
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void Write(Byte[] data)
        {
            if (FSerialPort.IsOpen) FSerialPort.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public String ReadLine()
        {
            String rValue;
            if (FSerialPort.IsOpen)
                rValue = FSerialPort.ReadLine();
            else
                rValue = null;

            return rValue;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public String Read(Int32 count)
        {
            String rValue = null;
            if (FSerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                Char[] buffer = new Char[count];
                FSerialPort.Read(buffer, 0, count);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(buffer);

                rValue = sb.ToString();
            }

            return rValue;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public Byte[] ReadBytes(Int32 count)
        {
            Byte[] rValue = null;
            if (FSerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                rValue = new Byte[count];
                FSerialPort.Read(rValue, 0, count);
            }

            return rValue;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public Char ReadChar()
        {
            return (Char)FSerialPort.ReadChar();
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public Int32 ReadByte()
        {
            return FSerialPort.ReadByte();
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public SerialPort NativeObject
        {
            get { return FSerialPort; }
        }
    }
}
```